# ASP.net 4.6 MVC 5 Autofac Object per Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

In my ASP.net MVC Application I want to set a value to an object which should be "exported" per session. I tried like this:

**The object i want:**

```
    public class Core : ICore {

    public Core() {
        UserSession = new UserSession();
    }

    public UserSession UserSession { get; set; }
}
```

**global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start() {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //register ICore
        builder.RegisterType<Core.Core>().As<ICore>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

**The place where i set the value to the object (UserController):**

```
public class UserController : BaseController {
    private readonly ICore _core;
    private readonly IUserDomain _userDomain;

    public UserController(ICore core, IUserDomain userDomain) {
        _core = core;
        _userDomain = userDomain;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginForm form) {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var user = _userDomain.GetByName(form.Username);
            if (user != null) {
                // Set Value
                _core.UserSession.CurrentUser = user;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return View(form);
    }
}
```

The Places where i need this Session object

**1st in the same Application:**
(Here ICore is not null but the CurrentUser which i set before in the Controller is null)

```
    public class ClaimsAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {

    public ICore Core { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        //Here is CurrentUser null
        var currentUser = Core.UserSession.CurrentUser;
        return currentUser != null;
    }
}
```

**2nd in another Project (SQL Context):**

```
public class BaseContext <TModel> where TModel : BaseModel {
    protected readonly ICore Core;
    protected NHibernateSession NHibernateSession;

    public BaseContext(ICore core) {
        Core = core;
    }

    public virtual bool Save(TModel model) {
        if (Core.UserSession.CurrentUser == null) {
            return false;
        }
        model.CreatedBy = Core.UserSession.CurrentUser.Id;
        model.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        using (var session = NHibernateSession.SessionFactory.OpenSession()) {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) {
                session.Save(model);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

    public class PageContext : BaseContext<Page>, IPageContext {

    public PageContext(ICore core, NHibernateSession nHibernateSession) : base(core) {
        NHibernateSession = nHibernateSession;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your global.asax, you can register `ICore` like this :

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("no httpcontext available");
    }

    ICore core = HttpContext.Current.Session["ICore"] as ICore;
    if (core == null)
    {
        core = new Core();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ICore"] = core;
    }

    return core;
}).As<ICore>();
```

In this case, each time *Autofac* will resolve a `ICore` it will look in the session and add a new instance to it when needed.